# matlab: any command for substitute of for & if

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I have a question about using for and if loop

If I have a situation like this

I have data_result R in matrix a by b where a is the index on question and b is the answer

and in depends on data M(x by y) where x  = a

I have code like

```
for i = 1:a
    if M(i) > constant 1
      R(i) = a;
    else if M(i) > constant 2
      R(i) = b;
    else
      R(i) = c;
    end
end
```

I just wondering that is there any possible solution of the idea to solve this minimize for loop and condition if else

Comment: When you say "a*b", do you mean that R is `a` rows by `b` columns in size, or that it's the result of matrix multiplying the two matrixes `a` and `b`? Or something else?

Comment: yes it mean matrix R has a rows by b columns size

Comment: Okay. That's often written as "a x b" or "a-by-b" instead, to avoid confusion with the "a*b" syntax for multiplication.

Comment: Are R and M the same size? Are you trying set each element of M based on a test on a corresponding element of R, or do some operation on entire rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "vectorized" update of selected elements using `>` or other elementwise comparisons on whole arrays, and then assigning using indexes. The tests return boolean arrays that you can use to index in to the input arrays or other arrays with corresponding dimensions.

```
R = repmat(c, size(M));
% Do tests in order of increasing selectivity
R(M > 1) = a;
R(M > 2) = b;
```

Comment: If you had some prior knowledge about the distribution you could make it even faster by making the two vectorized lookups operate on the minimal subsets.  For instance if you had the idea that M was 80% b, 12%c, and 8% a then you could make R=b*ones(size(M)); R(M==1)=a; R(M>2)=c; and you could get faster runs for it.  I think that repmat might be slower than 'R=c.*ones(size(M));'.  Ones is fast and so is dot-multiply.

Comment: And so is repmat, and so is == and > and < and (). Did you benchmark repmat vs b*ones() before guessing one was faster? All these operations are fast enough there's no practical difference until you get to millions of elements. If you were using nontrivial operations in your tests, it might be worth doing the minimal subset logic. But the example code you have is wrong; it still does does the tests on all elements of the input; you have to do additional index mapping to work on subsets, which itself involves overhead.

Comment: The asker is about big data.  Even with millions of elements I would use the for loop.  Computers are fast, and for-loops are fast to write.

clc

N=100;
M=ones(1000,1000);

tic
for i=1:N
    R=repmat(9,size(M));
    clear R
    
end
toc
    
tic
for i=1:N
    R=9.*ones(size(M));
    clear R
    
end
toc

Elapsed time is 1.274471 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.608783 seconds.
>> 

Repmat is half the speed, twice as long to do the same thing.

Comment: @EngrStudent: The asker didn't say anything about their data size. And performance is going to vary a lot depending on OS, versions, hardware, data size, etc. I wouldn't generalize from a simple test like that. Here's me running your same sample code (`N=100; M=ones(1000,1000); tic; for i=1:N; R=repmat(9,size(M)); clear R; end; toc; tic; for i=1:N; R=9.*ones(size(M)); clear R; end; toc`). time is 0.156673 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.543528 seconds.
Here, repmat is 3x faster. It varies.

Comment: @EngrStudent: Computers are fast, for-loops are fast to write, but _in Matlab specifically_, which is what asker is asking about, for-loops are sometimes slow because the per-operation overhead for M-code operations like function calls is relatively high. So idiomatic Matlab code uses vectorized operations. They execute faster, and once you understand the idiom, they can be faster to write. Notice how much shorter and simpler my example code is than the original asker's.

Comment: I liked your answer.  I find it sufficient.  I upvoted it when I saw it and did not add my own.  Simple is in the mind of the comprehender.  Sometimes the vectorized code can be confusing itself.